# Anyway to turn off the health LED on a DL360 g9?

Tags: datacenter, ilo, hpe

We have an out of warranty test machine (HP DL360 G9) that we are keeping around, but don't want to repair. The health LED is on and that leads the good datacenter folks to come in and freak out on our behalf. Good folks. Is there a way to "acknowledge" the health lamp so we can keep our wonderful datacenter folks from thinking the sky is falling every time they pass our rack?

Comment: "Put tape over it" comment in 3... 2... 1... ;)

Comment: Have you actually logged in to iLO to see what the problem is?

Comment: @Jeshizaemon not good enough, tape might fall off.  Cut the wires or legs of the LED.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Yep, Smart Storage Battery has gone bad.

Comment: You could just replace it...

Comment: @MichaelHampton But it has been decided to let it run until it dies. So, unless we find some hack to turn off LEDs, looks like I might have to do some surgery...

Comment: Much in line with the tape comment, a little roughing up of the area around the LED (or some very small holes) and a blob of JB Weld or similar non-transparent hardening epoxy.  Roughing up or holes is to allow a mechanical bond.

Comment: Really? It could be years before it "dies". Or never. That decision doesn't make much sense, when fixing it is cheap and easy, and somebody will eventually forget that this machine doesn't have a battery backup and will try to do something actually important with it....Not that that has ever happened to anyone anywhere ever.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Wish I was the one making the decision. In the end, I'll probably just retire it quietly so that the "oops, we used the test machine for something important" doesn't happen.

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately there is no way to turn off the health LED. Since you are planning to run it till it dies, I can only think of the the tape idea or paint the led to green or add a green tint sticker :D

Comment: lol, a green sticker! Now there's an idea.

Comment: Make it a blue sticker, because "yellow and blue make green"...